# Assume $f:X \to Y$ is Borel measurable and $g:X \to Y$ such that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. Then $f_\sharp \mu = g_\sharp \mu$

Tags: measure-theory

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments.

---

**Theorem:** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $\mu$ a complete Borel probability measure on $X$. Assume $f:X \to Y$ is Borel measurable and $g:X \to Y$ such that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e., i.e., there is a $\mu$-null set $N \subset X$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in N^c := X \setminus N$. Then $f_\sharp \mu = g_\sharp \mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be a Borel subset of $Y$. First, we prove that $g$ is also Borel measurable. We have
$$
g^{-1} (B) = (g^{-1} (B) \cap N) \cup (g^{-1} (B) \cap N^c) .
$$

Because $\mu$ is complete, $g^{-1} (B) \cap N$ is Borel measurable. On the other hand, $f_{\restriction N^c} = g_{\restriction N^c}$, so $g^{-1} (B) \cap N^c = f^{-1} (B) \cap N^c$ is Borel measurable. This implies $g^{-1} (B)$ is Borel measurable. Second,
$$
\begin{align}
f_\sharp \mu (B) &= \mu(f^{-1} (B)) \\
&= \mu(f^{-1} (B) \cap N) + \mu(f^{-1} (B) \cap N^c) \\
&= \mu(f^{-1} (B) \cap N^c) \\
&= \mu(g^{-1} (B) \cap N^c) \quad  \text{because} \quad f_{\restriction N^c} = g_{\restriction N^c} \\
&= \mu(g^{-1} (B) \cap N) + \mu(g^{-1} (B) \cap N^c) \\
&= \mu(g^{-1} (B)) = g_\sharp \mu (B). 
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.